# Removing a specific item from a variable...?

Tags: macos, bash

In my bash script, I want to remove two items from a variable.  Specifically, on OS X, I am listing the contents of the /Users directory and want the variable not to contain ".localized" or "Shared".  Here is the code...

```
# List the system users and load them into a variable
systemUsers=`ls /Users/`
```

This variable will list all user home directories.  How can I ensure that the variable won't contain the two items mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, have you try `systemUsers=$(ls /Users/ | grep -v .localize | grep -v Shared)` ?

Comment: This was the ticket!  The earlier suggested solution using "shopt" basically worked but provided the full path.  All I want is the user home directory name, and this solution provided that.  Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome :-) You can find other option by typing `man grep` in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extglob` for this:

```
shopt -s extglob
echo /Users/!(Shared|.localized)
```

To store results in an array:

```
arr=(/Users/!(Shared|.localized))
```